# Hibernate search for read-only database

Tags: full-text-search, hibernate-search, readonly

I need to perform full text queries with hibernate, and Hibernate Seach seems to be a good choice, and the capabilities for matching synonyms, etc are very interesting. The problem is that my application only does queries, and another applications do the inserts/updates/deletes. I don't know if "hibernate seach" can mantain the text indexes updated in this scenario, and in the case it can't, I think that rebuild the indexes in each query is not an option (is it?).

The application that performs the updates in the database has the ability of generating an event to my application. This could be an opportunity to refresh the indexes...

Any suggestion will be apreciated. Thanks in advance:

Carlos.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this other application is not a Java application which could trigger the index updates. In this case you have indeed to make sure that the indexes get updated properly. If you can send a notification to the Java application to trigger the updates a lot is already won. If you for example can send the primary keys of the entities which have changed you can use these ids to update only these entities in the index. You won't have to rebuild the whole index. Another approach is to use a last updated column. When the indexing app gets a notifications it selects the records which have changed since the last trigger for updates. It depends a little how your tables look like and what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, full index rebuild it too long is most of cases. But if you able to receive events - it is not a problem. Just reindex entity [manually](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/manual-index-changes.html#d0e5407) when event received.

Btw, if you use PostgreSQL or Oracle check [PostgreSQL FTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch.html) and [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm).